# Google Maps mouseover with markers and data layer behavior

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

In the following Google Map I have event listeners on `mouseover` and `mouseout` for my markers and the data layer which display data as appropriate.

The issue I have is that when the mouse leaves a marker it does not display the information from the data layer. I have tried this with a single marker and layer and the behavior works as expected. What am I doing wrong?

I am adding the event listeners on each `marker` and event listeners on the `map.data` layer.

```js
var map = null;
var markers = [];
var $info = $('#info');

var mapOptions = {
  center: null,
  zoom: 12,
  zoomControlOptions: {
    position: google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_BOTTOM
  },
};

google.maps.event.addDomListener(
  window,
  'load',
  initialize
);

function initialize() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
    mapOptions
  );

  addSchools();
  addWards();

  // Style wards
  map.data.setStyle(function(feature) {
    return {
      fillColor: 'green',
      fillOpacity: 0.2,
      strokeWeight: 1,
      strokeColor: 'grey'
    };
  });

  // Info on wards
  map.data.addListener('mouseover', function(event) {
    var title = event.feature.getProperty('title');
    $info.html(title).show();
  })

  map.data.addListener('mouseout', function(event) {
    $info.hide();
  })

};

function addWards() {
  var wards = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('wards').innerHTML);
  for (var i = 0; i < wards.length; i++) {
    var geoJsonLayer = wards[i];
    $.ajax({
      url: geoJsonLayer.Url,
      dataType: 'json',
      type: 'GET',
      title: geoJsonLayer["Ward Name"],
      success: function(data) {
        var layer = {
          "type": "FeatureCollection",
          "features": [
            { "type": "Feature",
             "geometry": data,
             "properties": {
               "title" : this.title
             }
            }
          ]
        }
        map.data.addGeoJson(layer);
      }
    })
  }
}

function addSchools() {
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  var schools = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('schools').innerHTML);
  for (var i = 0; i < schools.length; i++) {
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(schools[i].Latitude, schools[i].Longitude);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      map: map,
      icon: {
        path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
        scale: 6,
        fillColor: 'yellow',
        fillOpacity: 0.9,
        strokeWeight: 1,
        strokeColor: 'grey'
      },
      position: latlng,
      title: schools[i].School,
      zIndex: 999
    })

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', function() {
      $info.html(this.title).show();
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseout', function() {
      $info.hide();
    });

    bounds.extend(latlng);
  }
  map.fitBounds(bounds);
};
```

```css
html, body, #map-canvas {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

#info {
  background: white;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  display: none;
  font-family: Roboto,Arial,sans-serif;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  top: 10px;
  width: 400px;
}

#info h1 {
  border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 0;
  padding-bottom: 4px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

#info th {
  padding-right: 10px;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCQVBfiFu8nTpJHZ-O9TdoxCew4Fmf8ahU"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script> 
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
<div id="info"></div>
<script type="application/json" id="schools">
[
  {
    "School": "University of Huddersfield",
    "Latitude": 53.643714,
    "Longitude": -1.777711
  },
  {
    "School": "Islamia Girls' High School",
    "Latitude": 53.644997,
    "Longitude": -1.787971
  },
  {
    "School": "Mount Pleasant Junior School",
    "Latitude": 53.635446,
    "Longitude": -1.793422
  },
  {
    "School": "Mount Pleasant Primary School",
    "Latitude": 53.635446,
    "Longitude": -1.793422
  },
  {
    "School": "Mount Pleasant Infant and Nursery School",
    "Latitude": 53.636496,
    "Longitude": -1.792781
  },
  {
    "School": "Thornton Lodge Nursery School",
    "Latitude": 53.636373,
    "Longitude": -1.799875
  },
  {
    "School": "Spring Grove Junior Infant and Nursery School",
    "Latitude": 53.643891,
    "Longitude": -1.791611
  },
  {
    "School": "Greenhead College",
    "Latitude": 53.647023,
    "Longitude": -1.793668
  },
  {
    "School": "Paddock Junior Infant and Nursery School",
    "Latitude": 53.644532,
    "Longitude": -1.809245
  },
  {
    "School": "Huddersfield Grammar School",
    "Latitude": 53.648293,
    "Longitude": -1.812012
  },
  {
    "School": "St David's School",
    "Latitude": 53.648293,
    "Longitude": -1.812012
  },
  {
    "School": "Birkby Infant and Nursery School",
    "Latitude": 53.656977,
    "Longitude": -1.791138
  },
  {
    "School": "Rathbone Choices",
    "Latitude": 53.649792,
    "Longitude": -1.788904
  },
  {
    "School": "Mountjoy House School",
    "Latitude": 53.651409,
    "Longitude": -1.793404
  },
  {
    "School": "Highfields School",
    "Latitude": 53.653566,
    "Longitude": -1.793379
  },
  {
    "School": "Edgerton College",
    "Latitude": 53.653885,
    "Longitude": -1.801109
  },
  {
    "School": "Birkby Junior School",
    "Latitude": 53.658602,
    "Longitude": -1.784578
  },
  {
    "School": "New Directions College",
    "Latitude": 53.647137,
    "Longitude": -1.772398
  }
]
</script>
<script type="application/json" id="wards">
 [
   {
  "Ward Name":"Almondbury",
  "Url":"http://mapit.mysociety.org/area/135207.geojson"
   },
   {
  "Ward Name":"Ashbrow",
  "Url":"http://mapit.mysociety.org/area/8998.geojson"
   },
   {
  "Ward Name":"Crossland Moor and Netherton",
  "Url":"http://mapit.mysociety.org/area/135206.geojson"
   },
   {
  "Ward Name":"Dalton",
  "Url":"http://mapit.mysociety.org/area/9005.geojson"
   },
   {
  "Ward Name":"Greenhead",
  "Url":"http://mapit.mysociety.org/area/9003.geojson"
   },
   {
  "Ward Name":"Lindley",
  "Url":"http://mapit.mysociety.org/area/9002.geojson"
   },
   {
  "Ward Name":"Newsome",
  "Url":"http://mapit.mysociety.org/area/8996.geojson"
   }
 ]
</script>
```

Comment: I can't see the layers on the map...Am I missing something?

Comment: They should appear as green boundaries with yellow markers, no problems running the code snippet here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `mouseover` event doesn't fire again for the polygons if the marker is on top of a polygon.  It only fires the first time you enter the polygon.

Not sure if it is a bug or the expected behavior. One option to fix this would be to track the the mouseover state for the polygons and redisplay the polygon information on the mouseout event of a marker.

```
// global variable
var state = {area: "", over: false};

// Info on wards
map.data.addListener('mouseover', function(event) {
  var title = event.feature.getProperty('title');
  $info.html(title).show();
  // save state
  state = {area: title, over: true};
})

map.data.addListener('mouseout', function(event) {
  $info.hide();
  // update state
  state.over = false;
})

// marker mouseout handler
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseout', function() {
  $info.hide();
  console.log("mouseout:"+this.title);
  // if still over polygon, display info
  if (state.over) { $info.html(state.area).show() };
});
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/j7411f7p/)

**code snippet:**

```js
var map = null;
var markers = [];
var $info = $('#info');
var state = {
  area: "",
  over: false
};

var mapOptions = {
  center: null,
  zoom: 12,
  zoomControlOptions: {
    position: google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_BOTTOM
  },
};

google.maps.event.addDomListener(
  window,
  'load',
  initialize
);

function initialize() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
    mapOptions
  );

  addSchools();
  addWards();

  // Style wards
  map.data.setStyle(function(feature) {
    return {
      fillColor: 'green',
      fillOpacity: 0.2,
      strokeWeight: 1,
      strokeColor: 'grey'
    };
  });

  // Info on wards
  map.data.addListener('mouseover', function(event) {
    var title = event.feature.getProperty('title');
    $info.html(title).show();
    state = {
      area: title,
      over: true
    };
  })

  map.data.addListener('mouseout', function(event) {
    $info.hide();
    state.over = false;
  })

};

function addWards() {
  var wards = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('wards').innerHTML);
  for (var i = 0; i < wards.length; i++) {
    var geoJsonLayer = wards[i];
    $.ajax({
      url: geoJsonLayer.Url,
      dataType: 'json',
      type: 'GET',
      title: geoJsonLayer["Ward Name"],
      success: function(data) {
        var layer = {
          "type": "FeatureCollection",
          "features": [{
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": data,
            "properties": {
              "title": this.title
            }
          }]
        }
        map.data.addGeoJson(layer);
      }
    })
  }
}

function addSchools() {
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  var schools = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('schools').innerHTML);
  for (var i = 0; i < schools.length; i++) {
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(schools[i].Latitude, schools[i].Longitude);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      map: map,
      icon: {
        path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
        scale: 6,
        fillColor: 'yellow',
        fillOpacity: 0.9,
        strokeWeight: 1,
        strokeColor: 'grey'
      },
      position: latlng,
      title: schools[i].School,
      zIndex: 999
    })

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', function() {
      $info.html(this.title).show();
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseout', function() {
      $info.hide();
      if (state.over) {
        $info.html(state.area).show()
      };
    });

    bounds.extend(latlng);
  }
  map.fitBounds(bounds);
};
```

```css
html,
body,
#map-canvas {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
#info {
  background: white;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  display: none;
  font-family: Roboto, Arial, sans-serif;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  top: 10px;
  width: 400px;
}
#info h1 {
  border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 0;
  padding-bottom: 4px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
#info th {
  padding-right: 10px;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCQVBfiFu8nTpJHZ-O9TdoxCew4Fmf8ahU"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
<div id="info"></div>
<script type="application/json" id="schools">
  [ { "School": "University of Huddersfield", "Latitude": 53.643714, "Longitude": -1.777711 }, { "School": "Islamia Girls' High School", "Latitude": 53.644997, "Longitude": -1.787971 }, { "School": "Mount Pleasant Junior School", "Latitude": 53.635446,
  "Longitude": -1.793422 }, { "School": "Mount Pleasant Primary School", "Latitude": 53.635446, "Longitude": -1.793422 }, { "School": "Mount Pleasant Infant and Nursery School", "Latitude": 53.636496, "Longitude": -1.792781 }, { "School": "Thornton Lodge
  Nursery School", "Latitude": 53.636373, "Longitude": -1.799875 }, { "School": "Spring Grove Junior Infant and Nursery School", "Latitude": 53.643891, "Longitude": -1.791611 }, { "School": "Greenhead College", "Latitude": 53.647023, "Longitude": -1.793668
  }, { "School": "Paddock Junior Infant and Nursery School", "Latitude": 53.644532, "Longitude": -1.809245 }, { "School": "Huddersfield Grammar School", "Latitude": 53.648293, "Longitude": -1.812012 }, { "School": "St David's School", "Latitude": 53.648293,
  "Longitude": -1.812012 }, { "School": "Birkby Infant and Nursery School", "Latitude": 53.656977, "Longitude": -1.791138 }, { "School": "Rathbone Choices", "Latitude": 53.649792, "Longitude": -1.788904 }, { "School": "Mountjoy House School", "Latitude":
  53.651409, "Longitude": -1.793404 }, { "School": "Highfields School", "Latitude": 53.653566, "Longitude": -1.793379 }, { "School": "Edgerton College", "Latitude": 53.653885, "Longitude": -1.801109 }, { "School": "Birkby Junior School", "Latitude": 53.658602,
  "Longitude": -1.784578 }, { "School": "New Directions College", "Latitude": 53.647137, "Longitude": -1.772398 } ]
</script>
<script type="application/json" id="wards">
  [ { "Ward Name":"Almondbury", "Url":"http://mapit.mysociety.org/area/135207.geojson" }, { "Ward Name":"Ashbrow", "Url":"http://mapit.mysociety.org/area/8998.geojson" }, { "Ward Name":"Crossland Moor and Netherton", "Url":"http://mapit.mysociety.org/area/135206.geojson"
  }, { "Ward Name":"Dalton", "Url":"http://mapit.mysociety.org/area/9005.geojson" }, { "Ward Name":"Greenhead", "Url":"http://mapit.mysociety.org/area/9003.geojson" }, { "Ward Name":"Lindley", "Url":"http://mapit.mysociety.org/area/9002.geojson" }, {
  "Ward Name":"Newsome", "Url":"http://mapit.mysociety.org/area/8996.geojson" } ]
</script>
```

Comment: The snippet wouldn't run but the proof of concept did the trick